# Rails 5.1 API - index method with filter, pagination and scopes - how to simplify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have an index method in a Rails API controller that is quite horrendous, as you can see below.

I am sure there is a more Ruby or Rails way to write this.

The action supports paging and filtering (by a filter= query parameter) and also can supply a customer-id to restrict what is returned to only proposals relevant to the provided customer.

I wonder if maybe I should separate the customer functionality to a separate endpoint? (eg. customers/:id/proposals). Of course that endpoint would also need to support paging and filter, so I think I might not end up with DRY code. Is there a way (like with Concerns) that I could make this index code simpler (ie. without all the `if...then...else`)?

```
  def index
    if params[:page].present?
      page = params[:page]
      if params[:filter].present?
        if params[:customer_id].present?
          @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals.customer(params[:customer_id]).search(params.slice(:filter)).page(page)
        else
          @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals.search(params.slice(:filter)).page(page)
        end
      else
        if params[:customer_id].present?
          @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals.customer(params[:customer_id]).page(page)
        else
          @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals.page(page)
        end
      end
      render json: @proposals, root: 'proposals', meta: pagination_dict(@proposals)
    else
      render status: :bad_request, json: { message: "Please supply page parameter" }
    end
  end
```

Here are the `Proposal` model scopes:

```
  default_scope { order("updated_at DESC") }
  scope :filter, -> (term) { where("lower(first_name) || ' ' || lower(last_name) || ' ' || lower(email) LIKE ? OR qd_number::text LIKE ?", "%#{term.downcase}%", "%#{term}%") }  
  scope :customer, -> (customer_id) { where customer_id: customer_id }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:page].present?
    @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals.page(params[:page])

    @proposals = @proposals.customer(params[:customer_id]) if params[:customer_id].present?
    @proposals = @proposals.search(params.slice(:filter))  if params[:filter].present?

    render json: @proposals, root: 'proposals', meta: pagination_dict(@proposals)
  else
    render status: :bad_request, json: { message: "Please supply page parameter" }
  end
end
```

Furthermore you might want to handle the error in a `before_action`:

```
before_action :check_required_parameters, only: :index

def index
  @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals.page(params[:page])

  @proposals = @proposals.customer(params[:customer_id]) if params[:customer_id].present?
  @proposals = @proposals.search(params.slice(:filter))  if params[:filter].present?

  render json: @proposals, root: 'proposals', meta: pagination_dict(@proposals)
end

private

def check_required_parameters
  return if params[:page].present?

  render status: :bad_request, json: { message: "Please supply page parameter" }
end
```

Or you might want to change your scopes to handle blank values:

```
# in the model
scope :filter, -> (term) { where("lower(first_name) || ' ' || lower(last_name) || ' ' || lower(email) LIKE ? OR qd_number::text LIKE ?", "%#{term.downcase}%", "%#{term}%") if term.present? }  
scope :customer, -> (customer_id) { where(customer_id: customer_id) if customer_id.present? }

# in the controller
def index
  if params[:page].present?
    @proposals = current_user.retailer.proposals
      .customer(params[:customer_id])
      .search(params.slice(:filter))
      .page(params[:page])

    render json: @proposals, root: 'proposals', meta: pagination_dict(@proposals)
  else
    render status: :bad_request, json: { message: "Please supply page parameter" }
  end
end
```